# What are denumerable sets exactly?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Set $I = \{x \mid x \text{ is a positive integer}\}$

Set $J = \{x \mid 2 < x < 5\}$

Both sets $I$ and $J$ are infinite, I get that. But why is set $I$ denumerable and set $J$ nondenumerable? I just can't get my head around it.

Comment: Have you seen such an argument before? (Note: "uncountable" is another way of saying "nondenumerable") https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument

Comment: No, I haven't come across Canto's diagonal argument before. I will try to understand it. Thanks